# Generate java class with @XmlJavaTypeAdapter from scheme

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling, xjc

I have xsd schema and my classes are generated from that schema.

I need XmlAdapter for correct marshaling/unmarshalling of some types.
I created such adapter (e.g `MyAdapter`), but I can't just add it via @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyAdapter.class) because my classes are generated from the scheme.

Is it possible to generate class from scheme with adapter defined ?

e.g I have scheme - > I want

```
@XmlType(name = "someName")
@XmlEnum
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyAdapter.class)
public enum MyGeneratedClass {
   // ...
}
```

`XJC` is used to create Java classes from scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `<xs:annotation>`

For instance :

```
<xs:simpleType name="myType">
    <xs:annotation>
       <xs:appinfo>
        <xjc:javaType name="com.seriouscompany.seriousproduct.MyType"
          adapter="com.seriouscompany.seriousproduct.MyAdapter" /> 
       </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    ....
```

This should help.

Comment: does not works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037803/why-jaxb-adapter-annotation-is-not-added-to-the-proxy-classes