# why jaxb adapter annotation is not added to the proxy classes

Tags: java, xml, gradle, jaxb, jaxb2

My XSD looks like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
...
  <xs:element name="person">
    <xs:complexType>
      ...
      <xs:attribute name="first_name" use="optional" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
...
</xs:schema>
```

I can't manage to add my adapter annotation to the concrete field ( generated proxy class must have my adapter annotation). **So the result should be the following**:

```
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=StringAdapter.class, type=String.class)
    @XmlAttribute(name = "first_name")
    protected String firstName;
```

but my binding does not do anything. Just like it does not exists.

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
  <bindings schemaLocation="XMLreq.xsd" node="/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='person']/xs:complexType/xs:attribute[@name='first_name']" >
           <xjc:javaType adapter="x.y.z.StringHashFunctionAdapter" name="java.lang.String" />
  </bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

I have **no error** during proxy class **generation**.

```
dependencies {
    xsd2java "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.7"
    xsd2java "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.7"
}
task xsd2java() {
    doLast {
        jaxbTargetDir.mkdirs()
        ant.taskdef(name: 'xjc', classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask', classpath: configurations.xsd2java.asPath)
        ant.jaxbTargetDir = jaxbTargetDir
        ant.xjc(destdir: '${jaxbTargetDir}',  package: 'x.y.z.request', schema: 'src/main/resources/XMLreq.xsd', binding: 'src/main/resources/bindings.jxb')
    }
}
```

and my adapter.

```
public class StringHashFunctionAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String marshal(String v) throws Exception { return "####hashed value####"; }
```

Any ideas?